# Serializing a List<object>

Tags: c#, xml, json

I have a generic list of type object and I am trying to serialize it , but deserializing doesn't fetch me good results.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
List<object> sample_list = new List<object>();
        sample_list.Add(new Sample() {  type=0,message="I am the first"});
        sample_list.Add(new Sample1() { type=1,message1 = "I am the 2" });
        sample_list.Add(new Sample2() { type=2,message2 = "I am the 3" });

       string serial= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sample_list);

       List<object> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(serial);
       lstbox.ItemsSource = list;

       foreach(var item in list)
       {
            if (item is Sample)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item is sample");
            }
       }
```

But the Message box never shows.
What should be done so that it can work correct?

Comment: Did you debug the application?

Comment: Why are you serializing and then deserializing ?

Comment: @adaam that is a very common thing to do if you want to check whether you have serialized your data in a way that allows you to correctly deserialize it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deserializing list into list of `object`, why you expect then CLR will recognize those objects as `Sample` or `Sample1`? Serialized JSON looks:

```
[{"type":0,"message":"I am the first"},{"type":1,"message1":"I am the 2"},{"type":2,"message2":"I am the 3"}]
```

So how JSON.NET could magically find out that they are `Sample` objects? Make a simple test to notice that `list[0].GetType().FullName` is `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`, not `Sample`.

If you want to deserialize to list of `Sample`, write:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sample>>(serial);
```

and then Json.NET will **try to match** each property from JSON into `Sample` properties (but of course it won't success sometimes as not objects are of type `Sample`).

If you want to serialize your list, your JSON should store information about used types, and there is built-in option for it in JSON.NET:

```
string serial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sample_list,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { 
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects 
    });
```

Then serialized JSON looks:

```
[{"$type":"ConsolePusher.Sample, ConsolePusher","type":0,"message":"I am the first"}, 
 {"$type":"ConsolePusher.Sample1, ConsolePusher","type":1,"message1":"I am the 2"},
 {"$type":"ConsolePusher.Sample2, ConsolePusher","type":2,"message2":"I am the 3"}]
```

So it will be able to recreate objects when deserializing:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(serial,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
        });
```

Comment: Your "fix" almost certainly won't work, because the instances are **not** all `Sample`; one is a `Sample`, one is a `Sample1`, one is a `Sample2`.

Answer (score 2):

The clue here should be the json:

```
[{"type":0,"message":"I am the first"},
 {"type":1,"message1":"I am the 2"},
 {"type":2,"message2":"I am the 3"}]
```

You are deserializing that as `List<object>`. So: there is **nothing** in either the json or the API call that gives it a hint that you want a `Sample`. If you want it to store the type name and use that during deserialization, you need to **enable that option**:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
};
string serial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sample_list, settings);

List<object> list =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(serial, settings);
```

Note that storing type names is brittle and implementation-specific; it will not work well in all scenarios. The json here becomes:

```
[{"$type":"Sample, ConsoleApplication43","type":0,"message":"I am the first"},
 {"$type":"Sample1, ConsoleApplication43","type":1,"message1":"I am the 2"},
 {"$type":"Sample2, ConsoleApplication43","type":2,"message2":"I am the 3"}]
```